# Locked out of Ghost Blog on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, ghost-blog

I have a Ghost app instance running on Open Shift. For some reason when I try to login into `myapp.domain/ghost` it is no longer able to find my email.

How do I change the admin email settings?

Answer (score 4):

I've adapted the following from the reference given by @niharvey in his step 5, which is unluckily offline. The complete procedure including the missing steps would be as follows:

What you need:

- root *(not really, just writing permissions)*
- Path to database (`$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/content/data`)
- [Bcrypt](https://web.archive.org/web/20140704182145/http://asecuritysite.com/encryption/bcrypt) hash of desired password (*we'll call it* `bcrypt-hash`)
- Email address used (`select` statement below)

SSH to your app:

```
rhc ssh appname
```

Start sqlite with appropriate database path:

```
$ cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/content/data
$ sqlite3 ghost.db
```

Display data, such as email address used and column names *(optional)*:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(users);
sqlite> select * from users;
sqlite> select email from users;
```

Unlock account and reset password:

```
sqlite> update users set status = 'active' ;
sqlite> UPDATE users SET password = 'bcrypt-hash' WHERE email = 'youremail@gmail.com';
```

Answer (score 1):

The process to reset the password is relatively simple.

1. ssh into your gear
   `rhc ssh <yourappname>`
2. cd into your app dir
   `cd app-root/runtime/repo`
   **Note**: *This is the location of your application code and you can also cd to it by using the `OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` environment varaible*
3. cd into the sqlite database directory
   `cd content/data`
4. Login to your sqlite instance
   `sqlite3 ghost.db`
5. And use the directions from http://www.poisoncontrolcentre.org/changing-your-admin-password-manually/

Comment: The site is down, that's why it's recommended to write out answers completely instead of redirecting to a external webpage. Luckily archive.org had a snapshot, so I've provided the instructions as a new answer.